# R multiple factors with same information

Tags: r

I have a dataset with multiple factor columns representing the same information. For instance: an object (= one row) can have multiple colors, but most of them only have one. The colors are stored in factor columns. I have constructed a small example below:

```
data.frame(y = c(1,2,1,4,2,3),
       color1 = c("r","b","b","g","r","b"),
       color2 = c("b",NA,"g",NA,NA,"r"),
       color2 = c(NA,NA,"r",NA,NA,NA))
```

I want to use all the colors as x-variables in a model. Now I know the correct option would be to construct a dummy variable for each unique color (i.e., blue, red, green, etc.). However, I was wondering if there is a function in R, that can do this for me, as it seems to me a common issue.

EDIT: transforming the information to a dummy variable per color, would result in the following:

```
data.frame(y = c(1,2,1,4,2,3),
              red = c(1,0,1,0,1,1),
              blue = c(1,1,1,0,0,1),
              green = c(0,0,1,1,0,0))
```

It is this information I want to eventually use in a model.

Other options I have considered:

- Just adding all factor variables as independent variables. This wouldn't be correct, as it would give different meaning to col1 = "r", col2 = "b" and col1 = "b", col2 = "r", but it should not, as the order does not matter.
- Another option would be to use interaction(), i.e., construct a new factor variable, with a different level for each combination of colors. Again, this is not what I want, as this would ignore the overlap in colors between col1 = "b", col2 = "r" and col1 = "b", col2 = "g".

Comment: Please show what your desired output would be with the example data you've shared.

Comment: See `?rgb` for how to create colors based on intensities for red, green, blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your dataset to a "long" dataset and then go wide again. This is very easy to do with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
unique(melt(setDT(mydf, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
            measure.vars = patterns("color"), na.rm = TRUE)[
              , variable := NULL])[
                , dcast(.SD, rn + y ~ value, length)]
#    rn y b g r
# 1:  1 1 1 0 1
# 2:  2 2 1 0 0
# 3:  3 1 1 1 1
# 4:  4 4 0 1 0
# 5:  5 2 0 0 1
# 6:  6 3 1 0 1
```